# Mention users in post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

I was just wondering that when someone mention username in post like [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228837/32475) does user get notification about this? Or mentioning with link do that ? I got mentioned few times but I never got any notification.

If it doesn't work then can't we have it when someone mention a username ?

Comment: I think this proposal is better suited for [Meta Stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) as I doubt the mods have access to add any features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for mentions are described in [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/163749).

In a nutshell: mentions work in comments, for people already involved in discussion.

When mentions are used in questions/answers that's just usually to make clear it's about account name or just out of habit.

The reasons *not* to have them is mostly that this isn't email and who would *want* to be pinged every time someone feels like it? We are not addressing questions at some *specific* person and answers are already implicitly aimed at the question.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to be emailed, but some sort of box in the profile would be nice, especially if that were to include meta and chat.